AWS Cloudformation Stack API Gateway having Cors error when taking request from React App Locally
My locally hosted React application calls this AWS Serverless API Gateway built on CloudFormation Stack using Infrastructure Composer endpoint but encounters a CORS error. Although I have configured the Cors settings in my SAM template to allow all origins ('*'), the issue persists.
const fetchUser = async (userId) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://<api-id>.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/Prod/user/${userId}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // Include additional headers if required
      }
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Fetch error:', error);
  }
};

SAM
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  UserApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      DefinitionBody:
        openapi: '3.0'
        paths:
          /user/{userId}:
            get:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: GET
                type: aws_proxy
                uri: !Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${DemoUserMgmt.Arn}/invocations
              responses: {}
      Cors:
        AllowMethods: "'GET,POST,OPTIONS'"
        AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Amz-User-Agent'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'" # Adjust origin as needed

  DemoUserMgmt:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/function/user/UserManagement
      Handler: handler.handler
      Runtime: python3.12
      Events:
        UserApiGETuseruserId:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /user/{userId}
            Method: GET
            RestApiId: !Ref UserApi


Could you share the code on how request is handled by DemoUserMgmt function? From the documentation, it looks like you would also need to return cors headers from the request handler side

Without seeing the code you've used to handle the function it's difficult to identify the issue. But you need to make sure the lambda response for the GET request matches the headers in the OPTIONS Cors response.
